# How to change the format of the array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 19
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 20
        )

)
```

to

```
Array
(
    [0][question_id] => 19
    [1][question_id] => 20
)
```

Comment: Do you **need** the `question_id` in the end result?

Comment: Why not give this a go first? Don't just say you don't know how, why not research it? Using a `foreach()` would be one way of rebuilding this array.

Comment: If by any chance this array of objects is the result `json_decode`, you can  just get it as arrays to begin with using the second argument, e.g. `json_decode($json, true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function objectToArray($array) {
  if (is_object($array)) {
    $array = get_object_vars($array);
  }
  return (is_array($array)) ? array_map(__FUNCTION__, $array) : $array;
}
```

Example to use the function:

```
$array = array(
  (object) array('question_id' => '19'),
  (object) array('question_id' => '20'),
);

$result = objectToArray($array);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array 
 ( 
  [0] => Array ( [question_id] => 19 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [question_id] => 20 )
  )
```

Accessing array elements:

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
   echo  nl2br ($value['question_id']." \n "); 
}
```

Output:

```
19 
20
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `array_map` function:

```
$new_arr = array_map(function($o){
   return (array) $o;
}, $arr);             // $arr is your initial array of objects
```